# Jquery function works slower everytime the function fires on chrome

Tags: jquery, performance

My problem:
When I click the button, A popup screen appears. But, when I close that popup screen and reopen it again, it takes twice as long to load, everytime. So after a few clicks it takes already a few seconds.

I'm pretty sure this problem has to do with my jquery `$.get` function.

Someone knows the solution? Thank you in advance!

My code:

html:

```
<div id="postButtonHeader">
  <span>Post</span>
</div>
<div id="screenPopUp">
  <span id="screenPopUpInnerScreen">        
  </span>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#postButtonHeader').click(function(){
        $.get('php/popUp.php', {input: 'text'}, function(data){
            $('#screenPopUpInnerScreen').html(data);
            $('#screenPopUp').show();
        });
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function (e){
        var container = $('#screenPopUp');
        if (container.has(e.target).length === 0)
        {
            container.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT: it appears there is something wrong with my php code.

EDIT2: or not because it works fine on firefox.

PHP:

```
$input = $_GET['input'];
if($input == 'text'){
    $response = '

     **A whole bunch of html code**

    ';
}
echo $response;
```

Comment: I don't see anything that would cause it to continuously take longer after each click.

Comment: Try using event delegation on `#screenPopupInnerScreen` instead of adding it to `document.mouseup`

Comment: What browser are you using? Can you provide whatever is in `popUp.php`?

Comment: I'm using chrome, Just tried it on fireworks, works perfect there. And i've put my php code here.

Comment: My guess is that the server is taking longer to respond each time. Is your PHP doing different things each time? I see nothing here either.